# How to restrict user to input only a range of values in EditText box?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my `EditText` I need the user to input data only from 5 to 10 decimal values.

How do I achieve this?

If the user enters the value less than 5 or greater than 10 I need to prompt the user to enter the value between 5 and 10.

```
package com.sabari.results;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv5;
    TextView tv6;
    TextView tv7;
    TextView tv8;
    TextView tv10;
    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;
    EditText et4;
    EditText et5;
    EditText et6;
    EditText et7;
    EditText et8;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("CGPA Calculator");
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
                et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
                et7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
                et8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);


                tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                int n;

                double no1=0, no2=0, no3=0, no4=0, no5=0, no6=0, no7=0, no8=0;
                try {
                    no1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    no2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());}
                catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no3 = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no4 = Double.parseDouble(et4.getText().toString());
                }catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    no5 = Double.parseDouble(et5.getText().toString());
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    no6 = Double.parseDouble(et6.getText().toString());
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    no7 = Double.parseDouble(et7.getText().toString());
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }try {
                    no8 = Double.parseDouble(et8.getText().toString());
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (no1<=0) {    
                    n = 1;
                } else if (no3<=0||et3.equals("")) {
                    n = 2;
                } else if (no4<=0||et4.equals("")) {
                    n = 3;
                } else if (no5<=0||et5.equals("")) {
                    n = 4;
                } else if (no6<=0||et6.equals("")) {
                    n = 5;
                } else if (no7<=0||et7.equals("")) {
                    n = 6;
                } else if (no8<=0||et8.equals("")) {   
                    n = 7;
                } else {
                    n = 8;
                }

                double res = 0;

                if((no1<=10)&&(no2<=10)&&(no3<=10)&&(no4<=10)&&(no5<=10)&&(no6<=10)&&(no7<=10)&&(no8<=10)) {
                    res = (no1 + no2 + no3 + no4 + no5 + no6 + no7 + no8) / n;
                    tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : " + res);
                    Toast.makeText(Calculator.this, "Your CGPA is : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Calculator.this,"Please enter a valid GPA ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                et2.setText("");
                et3.setText("");
                et4.setText("");
                et5.setText("");
                et6.setText("");
                et7.setText("");
                et8.setText("");
                tv10.setText("Your CGPA is : ");
                et1.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but what is the current error that you are experiencing?  What output/result are you getting that isn't what you expect?  We can't just rewrite your code for you...

Answer (score 0):

After you parse the double they entered, you can do an easy if statement to check if the value they entered is between 5 and 10:

```
if (no1 < 5 || no1 > 10)
{
   // error... prompt them to enter value between 5 and 10
}
```

Alternatively, you can check for a correct value like so:

```
if (no1 >= 5 && no1 <= 10)
{
   // good value
}
```

Also, to only allow the user to enter a float value, you can set the `inputType` property of your EditTexts to `numberDecimal`:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    ... />
```

You can use an AlertDialog to let the user know the value they entered is incorrect.

As for your entire setup, you could make the code look a lot cleaner if you put all the EditTexts into a List/array, and all of the double values into another List. (A dictionary relating the two values would also be a good option). With this setup, your big section of 8 try-catch blocks would be reduced to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.Length; i++)
{
   try
   {
      nums[i] = Double.parseDouble(editTexts[i].getText().toString());
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Your block for checking if the values are between 5 and 10 would look similar, and you could have a Boolean value indicating whether or not an invalid value was found. The loop would break when one was found:

```
Boolean invalidFound = false;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length && !invalidFound; i++)
{
    invalidFound = (nums[i] < 5 || nums[i] > 10);
}

if (invalidFound)
{
    //error
}
else
{
    // good values
}
```

There are many ways to set this up. Some of the other options might be cleaner, but I wanted to show you an option that was relatively easier to understand.